# Apache Vysper Server Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, apache, xampp, server

First up all I want to let you know,I want chat server which I can integrate with spring.So I decide using Apache Vysper, but I cannot find proper documentation.
All I found was [this doc](http://mina.apache.org/vysper-project/documentation.html), but as I am new to xmpp, I don't understand the doc properly.
Please can any one help me configure Spring?

I have done this:

```
XMPPServer server = new XMPPServer("chatapp");

        server.start();

        // choose the storage you want to use
        StorageProviderRegistry providerRegistry = new JcrStorageProviderRegistry();
        //StorageProviderRegistry providerRegistry = new MemoryStorageProviderRegistry();

        final AccountManagement accountManagement = (AccountManagement) providerRegistry.retrieve(AccountManagement.class);

        if(!accountManagement.verifyAccountExists(EntityImpl.parse("user1@myembeddedjabber.com"))) {
            accountManagement.addUser(EntityImpl.parse("user1@myembeddedjabber.com"), "password1");
        }
```

But I dont understand how to send  and receive messages.

Comment: Hi @Manoj Singh. Did you manage to find a way to send and receive messages? I'm trying to write a chat application that runs on Smack and Vysper locally. If so could you please advise me on how to go about it. Maybe you could add an answer to your question here on how you went about it. Thank you. Hope you can help. Would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same, so perhaps I could give you some help....

I guess you are missing the following:

```
TCPEndpoint endpoint = new TCPEndpoint();
server.addEndpoint(endpoint);

server.setStorageProviderRegistry(providerRegistry);
```

Check it out, perhaps you need to add some modules, I have added the following:

```
server.addModule(new SoftwareVersionModule());
server.addModule(new EntityTimeModule());
server.addModule(new VcardTempModule());
server.addModule(new XmppPingModule());
server.addModule(new PrivateDataModule());
server.addModule(new RosterModule());
```

Hope I could help you,

Best regards
Markus

Comment: I have tried some other free services.But thanks for help.